# After adding StoreModule.forFeature (...) can not access to stored data

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux, ngrx

I have multiple projects in one angular 8 app...
Until now, I have in only one project `@ngrx/store` but
now I added `@ngrx/store` in every project and because of multiple stores, I need in every projects in  `app.module` import `StoreModule.forFeature`

```
imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    StoreModule.forFeature("project1store", fromStore.reducer1)
]
```

on the second project, I import

```
 imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        StoreModule.forFeature("project2store", fromStore.reducer2)
    ]
```

Problem is, in redux, I see all data but I can't take it. 
Also, I get an error for every reducer (all of this reducer worked before)

> store.js:994 @ngrx/store: The feature name "UserProfileReducer" does not exist in the state, therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it.  Be sure it is imported in a loaded module using StoreModule.forRoot('UserProfileReducer', ...) or StoreModule.forFeature('UserProfileReducer', ...).  If the default state is intended to be undefined, as is the case with router state, this development-only warning message can be ignored.

I import everything with a barrel (index.ts), in this case from `fromStore`. 
Every app have own barrel, and I check again, and every path is ok...

See on this image, all data is there, but now after `StoreModule.forFeature` can not take it
[image]

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is here
[image]

Before this I gett data like `store.siteReducer` but now I need to take it like `state.app2.siteReducer`

How to and where to add this `app1` or `app2`?

Thnx

**EDIT 2**

I can get data directly in component on this way

```
 select((state: any) => state.app1.SiteReducer)
.subscribe(res => {...})
```

But in this way, I need to make a change in whole app components.
How to make this directly in the selector?
I try this

```
 export const getState = createFeatureSelector<States>("app1");

export const getSite = createSelector(
  getState,
  (state: States) => state.app1.siteReducer
);
```

but get error

> Property 'app1' does not exist on type 'States'

Here are my states

```
export class States { 
data: { site: SiteModel | null; error: string }; 
} 
export const InitialState = {
 data: { site: null, error: null 
} 
};
```

If I remove in selector model `State` and put `any`, everything is working

```
export const getState = createFeatureSelector<States>("app1");

    export const getSite = createSelector(
      getState,
      (state: any) => state.app1.siteReducer
    );
```

I also try in states model add this

```
export class States {
  siteReducer: {data: { site: SiteModel | null; error: string }};
}

export const InitialState = {
  siteReducer: {data: { site: null, error: null }}
};
```

But now in store I have nested `siteReducer` object (this bellow is example)

```
app1{
    siteReducer{  // get this parent object
        siteReducer:{
            data:{..}
  }}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to config your feature selector to get nested level state

```
export const selectState = createFeatureSelector<ISomeState>(
    "app2"
);

export const selectSomeState = createSelector(
    selectState,
    state => state.someProp.someProp
);
```

Then config your reducer

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from "@ngrx/store";

export interface ISomeState {
    userState: IUserState ; // add your state interface here
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ISomeState> = {
    userState: userReducer // your reducer
};
```

So you will need to import the reducer into your module

```
 StoreModule.forFeature("app2", reducers)
```

If this not work please share your source code on github I will have a look

Comment: my state looks like this... `export class States {
  data: { user: UserProfileModel | null; error: string };
}

export const InitialState = {
  data: { user: null, error: null }
};
`  and when In `selector`, when I add ` state => state.someProp.someProp1` I get error `Property 'someProp' does not exist on type 'States'` . How to correctly add this in `State`

Comment: pls take a look at my question, on `EDIT 2` section

Comment: Rly sry but I can not share my code before release, and also, It is too big. Instead, I put all examples in question.... Thnx for undertand

Comment: Can you try to create small reproduce example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I will try and i will put URL link here